# click function for 'sort' to rearrange my obj data output in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am working on a series of 'click functions' that will essentially 'sort' or rearrange the output of my Obj data content, via the data field values, that I have already iterated over into my HTML.

For instance; below I am trying to create a 'sort' function with the 'Size' data field values - so when the click function is fired; the data within my HTML, will rearrange in accordance to smallest to greatest. I am achieving this sort logic, **the problem** I'm having is; **when the sort function is executed the content is not rearranging in HTML.** I can verify the logic in the console, but cannot get the HTML output to sort accordingly. Any thoughts?

*here is a visual. So clicking the 'Size' header should execute 'sort/rearrange'... by size.*

[image]

```
var json =[{
            "Name": "zips",
            "Type": "Directory",
            "DateModified": "6/14/2018 17:22:50",
            "Size": "5 KB",
        }, {
            "Name": "presets",
            "Type": "Directory",
            "DateModified": "5/11/2018 7:32:10",
            "Size": "2 KB",
        }, {
            "Name": "workflow",
            "Type": "Directory",
            "DateModified": "6/26/2018 10:29:59",
            "Size": "6 KB",
        },
];

var string ="";

for (i in json) {
    string +='<div class="row"><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="ck"></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-4"><span class="folders">'+json[i].Name+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3"><span class="directory">'+json[i].Type+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3"><span class="date-stamp">'+json[i].DateModified+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-1"><span class="date-size">'+json[i].Size+'</span></div></div>';
};

// Just outputs data into bootstrap columns, rows, from Obj data source

document.getElementsByClassName('update-data')[0].innerHTML =string

// Click function to reorganize data accordingly as 'sort' function

document.getElementById('size').addEventListener('click', function () {
    json.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseFloat(a.Size) - parseFloat(b.Size);
    });
});
```

The below is the relevant HTML.

```
<!-- etc -->
        <div>
          <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-1">
            <span id="size">Size</span>
            </div>
        </div>   

        <div class="update-data">
          <!-- output-->
        </div>
```

**I am getting the result in the console.. Just cannot get the outputted HTML to update.**

Comment: According to the code you have, the block that goes after "return parseFloat..." and that begins with "for (i in json)" isn't reachable.

Comment: Yes, I know; the code in there was a failed attempt. I restored original in OP.

Comment: Providing html too will be helpful

Comment: Then probably you need to change the `innerHTML` of the target element every time the "click" on "#size" happens. Merely sorting the array `json` won't affect the DOM, you need to explicitly change it each time the sorting is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already generated the html string using JSON data and inserted it into HTML of the page. **Sorting the JSON afterwards will not automatically change the HTML output**. What you have to do is, generate and insert new sorted HTML in place of original each time you sort the JSON. Something like this...

```
document.getElementById('size').addEventListener('click', function () {
    json.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseFloat(a.Size) - parseFloat(b.Size);
    });

    var str ="";

    for (i in json) {
        str +='<div class="row"><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="ck"></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-4"><span class="folders">'+json[i].Name+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3"><span class="directory">'+json[i].Type+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3"><span class="date-stamp">'+json[i].DateModified+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-1"><span class="date-size">'+json[i].Size+'</span></div></div>';
    };

    document.getElementsByClassName('update-data')[0].innerHTML =str;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! i was so close in concluding to this; now I just have to take in consideration for the second click on the 'sort' to rearrange back to default.